# Access Denied error while using PHP to connect to database in CentOS 7

Tags: php, mysql, centos7, remote-access

I am trying to connect to remote MySQL database at address 192.168.43.198. I am using CentOS 7 on both the nodes. my setup is as follows:

> **Database Node**
>
> IP: 192.168.43.198/24
>
> have installed necessary packages for MySQL DB
>
> Enabled necessary services and ports in firewall
>
> **Client Node**
>
> IP: 192.168.122.73/24
>
> Configured it for hosting a website. Installed httpd, mysql and dependencies.
>
> Enabled necessary services and ports in firewall

I have enabled remote login from mysql_secure_installation command
and have fired several queries in mysql which grant every user every permission

```
grant usage on *.* to DBuser@'%' identified by '123456789';
grant all privileges on *.* to DBuser@'%' identified by '123456789';
flush privileges;
```

in Client node, when I run the command

```
mysql -h 192.168.42.198 -u DBuser -p
Enter password: 123456789
```

I can access the database.

But my client node is also a web-server and when I try to connect to database using php, it is giving permission denied error

**/var/www/html/index.html** file

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Node 01</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form action="index.php" method="get">
    <input type="submit" value="Open DB">
  </form>

 </body>
</html>
```

I just have one button which points to the index.php file.

**/var/www/html/index.php** file

```
$link = mysqli_connect("192.168.43.198", "DBuser", "123456789","demo");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


echo 'Connected to the database.<br>';
```

database demo exists and I can manipulate it through command line as stated above and it works fine but when I click on the button in HTML, I am getting the error "ACCESS DENIED"

```
ERROR: Could not connect. Permission denied
```

I am using php 7.0 in Client Node here are the packages I installed in order to get php working

```
# rpm -qa | grep -i php
php-pdo-5.4.16-46.el7.x86_64
php-mcrypt-5.4.16-7.el7.x86_64
php-mysql-5.4.16-46.el7.x86_64
php-gd-5.4.16-46.el7.x86_64
php-ldap-5.4.16-46.el7.x86_64
php-5.4.16-46.el7.x86_64
php-common-5.4.16-46.el7.x86_64
php-cli-5.4.16-46.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: can you ping the db server from the client server ? and also tried with cli from client server

Comment: If SeLinux is enabled on your web server, check the SeLinux boolean: `httpd_can_network_connect_db`(or a similar).

Comment: @BerndBuffen Yes I can ping the DBServer and I can also conenct to it with CLI

Comment: @jxc can you guide me a bit more? what should I do after checking the boolean?

Comment: if it's *off*, then just turn it on: `sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db=on`

Comment: @jxc I have disabled SELinux on both the clients as of now. I dont know if that is the root of the problem but as SELinux is disabled, i think I dont need to set the boolean

Comment: yes, if you disabled SELinux, then no need to turn on that flag. It's always a good practice to enable SELinux in production env though. you can always run `sudo semanage boolean -l | grep http` to check if any flags need to be turned on.